# Solve misses positive solutions

Tags: equation-solving

Why `Solve` returns only negative solutions?

Let $n \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$. I want to find geometric position of roots of polynomial $p(x)=(x-1)^{2 n}+(x+1)^{2 n}$ in complex plane.

```
Solve[(x + 1)^(2 n) + (x - 1)^(2 n) == 0, x]
```

> $\left\{\left\{x\to \frac{1+e^{\frac{i \pi }{2 n}}}{-1+e^{\frac{i \pi }{2 n}}}\right\}\right\}=-i\cot\left(\dfrac{\pi}{4n}\right)$

But we know conjugates are also a solution i.e.

> $\left\{\left\{x\to -\frac{1+e^{\frac{i \pi }{2 n}}}{-1+e^{\frac{i \pi }{2 n}}}\right\}\right\}$

are also solutions.

We see that

```
With[{n = 1}, Solve[(x + 1)^(2 n) + (x - 1)^(2 n) == 0, x]]
```

returns

> $\{\{x\to -i\},\{x\to i\}\}$

and
$ \left\{\left\{x\to \frac{1+e^{\frac{i \pi }{2 n}}}{-1+e^{\frac{i \pi }{2 n}}}\right\}\right\} /. n -> 1$

returns

> $i$

[image]

Comment: The conjugates are given by negative values of `n`, e.g., `sol = Solve[(x + 1)^(2 n) + (x - 1)^(2 n) == 0, x][[1]]; sol /. {{n -> 1}, {n -> -1}}` evaluates to `{{x -> -I}, {x -> I}}`

Comment: Well $n\ge1$...

Comment: The condition/constraint  `n>=1` was not included in your `Solve`. If you do include it, neither `Solve` nor `Reduce` can solve the system.

Comment: @BobHanlon I think the problem is that for each *specific* n the conjugates should also be solutions; the requirement $n \geq 1$ is not actually relevant. Shouldn't `Solve[(x + 1)^(2 n) + (x - 1)^(2 n) == 0, x] /. n -> 1` give the same values as `Solve[(x + 1)^(2 n) + (x - 1)^(2 n) == 0 /. n -> 1, x]`? Currently it doesn't.

Comment: There is also no error message that some solutions might have been missed, which is a little disconcerting. Feeding it `Method -> Reduce`, where only equivalent transformations are used, makes `Solve` unable to solve this equation, suggesting that inequivalent transformations were used and thus that an error message should have been issued, as per the docs—unless something else is going on here?

Comment: @thorimur - `Conjugate[x /. sol] == (x /. sol /. n -> -n) // FullSimplify[#, Element[n, Reals]] &` evaluates to `True` which indicates that the conjugates are included.

Comment: @BobHanlon but that doesn't make sense, I don't think—`n` is supposed to be treated as a constant here specified in the original equation, not something that ranges over all numbers. If it was supposed to be arbitrary, that would be given as `C[1]`, right? After all, consider `Solve[a x + 1 == 0, x]`. This has the unique solution of `-1/a`. It doesn't mean that all `a` are admissible/included in the solution. as another ex, if i evaluate `Solve[x^2 == a^2, x]`, I get `{{x -> a}, {x -> -a}}`. I wouldn't expect to get just`{{x -> a}}` and say that I could then replace `a -> -a` to get the other.

Comment: @thorimur, remember that everything is treated as complex unless specified otherwise. Bob is correct that if the OP was assuming that `n >= 1` (or that `n` is real, for that matter), `Solve[]` should have been explicitly told, since it is not yet equipped with psychic abilities.

Comment: @J.M.'storpor Look at the problem a bit more closely, though—the requirement that $n \geq 1$ is actually irrelevant. The point is that `n` should in the generic case be treated as a *constant*, and that solutions are indeed missed even in the absence of any constraints on `n`.

Comment: @J.M.'storpor (Note that changing `n` in (only) the solution to `-n` seems to provide an alternate zero for *all* complex numbers `n`, not just those on a measure 0 set, at least from some experimental samples...)

Answer (score 1):

`Solve` really should throw a warning that some answers might be missed and to use `Reduce` for complete information. Doing `Reduce` first followed by `Solve` works

```
red = Reduce[(x + 1)^(2 n) + (x - 1)^(2 n) == 0, {x, n}]
sol = Solve[Last@red, x]
sol /. n -> 1 /. C[1] -> Range[2]
```

gives

```
C[1] \[Element] Integers && 1 + x != 0 && -1 + x != 0 && Log[-1 + x] - Log[1 + x] != 0 && 
 n == -((I π + 2 I π C[1])/(2 (Log[-1 + x] - Log[1 + x])))
{{x -> (1 + E^((I π)/(2 n) + (I π C[1])/n))/(-1 + E^((I π)/(2 n) + (I π C[1])/n))}}
{{x -> {I, -I}}}
```

as desired. This is a bit of an ugly hack, and still relies on the sketchy `Solve`. But in general `Solve` is not guaranteed to give full information like `Reduce` is.

Comment: While `Solve` giving the answer it does is not a bug, I think the lack of error messages you mention might be one (or at least be unintended behavior): from the docs, "Solve may use non-equivalent transformations to find solutions of transcendental equations and hence it may not find some solutions and may not establish exact conditions on the validity of the solutions found. **If this happens, an error message is issued.**"